# AngularJS - Manage button or input availability via model

Tags: angularjs

So, i'm quite stuck at this:

I have quite many buttons on my page, each button's availability is different in different context, for example:

When button "Add" is pressed, its state will be "disabled", Cancel and Save buttons will be available.

I came up with a solution to manage the stage of every buttons in one object call state, like this:

// This is the Controller

```
$scope.some_id = false;
 // With some UI interaction, $scope.some_id will be some integer value

 $scope.getContextBtnAdd = function(){ return $scope.some_id; };
 $scope.getContextBtnCancel = function(){ return !$scope.getContextBtnAdd(); };

 $scope.state = { 
     contextBtns : {
         btnAdd : $scope.getContextBtnAdd(),
         btnCancel: $scope.getContextBtnCancel(),
     },

     footerBtns : { Some footer buttons }
 };
```

// This is the View

```
<button name="add" ng-disabled="!state.contextBtns.btnAdd">Add</button>
```

"So when there is no product load, $scope.some_id will be false, so Add button will be available, but when user clicks on some products, the $scope.some_id  will be some integer value like 4,7 or 100... and the button will be disabled. " <=== That's what i want. But actually it doesn't work, the some_id changes but maybe the getContext function is never called. Right now i have to pass the getContext function to ng-disabled like this:

```
<button name="add" ng-disabled="!getContextBtnAdd()">Add</button>
```

But i want to manage them all via one object. So what's is my code problem and is there any better way to manage button, input....s availabilities?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When that line is executed:

```
$scope.state = { 
     contextBtns : {
         btnAdd : $scope.getContextBtnAdd(),
         btnCancel: $scope.getContextBtnCancel(),
     },

     footerBtns : { Some footer buttons }
 };
```

the state object is created, and its `contextBtns.btnAdd` attribute (for example) takes the value returned by `$scope.getContextBtnAdd()` **at that time**. The attribute value never changes after.

What you want instead is something that always has the value of `$scope.getContextBtnAdd()` every time it's evaluated. So you simply need the function itself:

```
$scope.state = { 
     contextBtns : {
         btnAdd : $scope.getContextBtnAdd,
         btnCancel: $scope.getContextBtnCancel,
     },

     footerBtns : { Some footer buttons }
 };
```

and in the view:

```
<button name="add" ng-disabled="!state.contextBtns.btnAdd()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works like a charm. Thank you very much. One thing more i wonder is if this is the right way for managing these buttons or inputs state? (Because i will have a lot of buttons and input fields)

Comment: if it works fine, and if you feel it's the most readable way and maintaineble way, then it's fine.